# Scroll to section on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm sure this is a pretty common question around here but after lots of research I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

So just a little warning; I'm really new into javascript and jQuery etc.

To the question! I'm trying to apply two images which you click on and it scrolls to the next or previous section.

So to get an overview of how it looks, here' a part of the HTML:

```
        <div id="scrollbuttons">
            <a href="#"><img id="prev" src="pics/prev.png"></img></a>
            <a href="#"><img id="next" src="pics/next.png"></img></a>
        </div>
```

And:

```
<div id="work">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="project">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="finish">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var actual = "work";
$("#prev").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var $prev = $("#"+actual).prev();
    if($prev.length == 0){
    return;
    }
    actual = $prev.attr("id");
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $prev.offset().top
    }, 1000);

});

$("#next").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var $next = $("#"+actual).next();
    if($next.length == 0){
    return;
    }
    actual = $next.attr("id");
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $next.offset().top
    }, 1000);

});
```

So what I'm trying to create is when you click on "next", the page should smoothly and automatically scroll to firstly, "work", then to "gallery" etc.

And when you press "prev", the page should again smoothly and automatically scroll back to the previous point.

I have the latest jQuery version and I'd like to not install plugins if it's not absolutely needed.

So I hope this is enough info to get some help, I'd really appreciate it since I'm really new to JS.

Thanks in advance

/Emil Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

You best use a plugin as they already invented the wheel: [jQuery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)
If you don't want to use the plugin, you can still learn from it by checking the code of the non-minified version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should introduce an indicator like a classname to determine the current active section and move that class together with scrolling when you click prev or next.

```
$('#scrollbuttons a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el, pos, active = $('#sectionContainer .active');

    if ($(this).is('#prev')) {
        el = active.prev();
    } else {
        el = active.next();
    }

    if (el.length) {
        pos = el.offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: pos
        }, 1000);
        el.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RNGq/).

---

If you want to integrate this with `scroll()` event, you also need to move that indicator when the `scrollTop` reaches a certain section:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#sectionContainer div').each(function(){
        var elTop = $(this).offset().top,
            elHeight = $(this).height();
        if(winTop >= elTop && winTop < elTop + elHeight){
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

With scrollbar [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RNGq/1/).

Comment: Hmm. I still can't seem to get it working :/ I've practiacally copied your code straight of and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks btw

Comment: I didn't mention it but probably with `<div id="sectionContainer">`. I added this element to wrap the sections as you can see on code `$('#sectionContainer div')`.

Comment: Yeah I have that included. Still can't seem to get it working. I'll try it around a bit. Thanks.